# IBOutlet why always weak and object of array ,dictionary etc are need to be strong

Tags: ios

i am new in ios programming , i just want to know why we use IBoutlet of every controller to be weak and other Need to strong 
can we define IBoutlet to be strong ? 
if yes then what is difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with ownership of the variable, since most `IBOutlets` are sub views of you view the ownership of the view lies with the view.

If you are creating your own properties you will need to retain the variable thus you make the property `strong`.